# SQL using order by and group by in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM billing_invoices 
WHERE reminder <> '' 
GROUP BY customer_sequence 
ORDER BY reminder DESC
```

so i want to get the most recent date from the `reminder` column however it is showing the earliest date

am i using the `group by` incorrectly?

Comment: Note that this is the most frequently asked question on SO under the mysql tag. However, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use grouping so as to get the most recent record per `customer_sequence`:

```
SELECT customer_sequence, MAX(reminder) AS max_reminder
FROM billing_invoices 
WHERE reminder <> '' 
GROUP BY customer_sequence
```

Then join back to the original table to get the rest of the fields:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM billing_invoices AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT customer_sequence, MAX(reminder) AS max_reminder
  FROM billing_invoices 
  WHERE reminder <> '' 
  GROUP BY customer_sequence
) AS t2 ON t1.customer_sequence = t2.customer_sequence AND
           t1.reminder = t2.max_reminder
```